# big Query adding a month to a search

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

looking to add a month to a search in gdelt.
If I use only the  year the code work great;
but if I looking for a month (like 2019-11) the result is empty.

tnx for your help!

```
  SELECT
  person,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials..israel_media_person_sum`
WHERE
  domain = 'walla.co.il'
  AND SUBSTR(CAST(DATE AS STRING), 1,4) = '2019'
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

EXTRACT(month  FROM  DATE) = 11 AND EXTRACT(year  FROM  DATE) = 2019

Check this
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

You may also try the one below   That you were trying to but I will go with option above.

CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE (Date)) AS STRING),"-",CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE (Date)) AS STRING))=‘2019_11’

Answer (score 0):

-- Do not forget to change Project.Dataset.Tale below to yours!
-- This is for January 2019

```
SELECT
  person,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  `gdeltgkgtry.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum`
WHERE
  domain = 'walla.co.il'
  AND SUBSTR(CAST(DATE AS STRING), 1,6) = '201901'
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

-- This is for all months in 2019

```
SELECT
  person,
  SUBSTR(CAST(DATE AS STRING), 1,6) AS year_month,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  `gdeltgkgtry.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum`
WHERE
  domain = 'walla.co.il'
  AND SUBSTR(CAST(DATE AS STRING), 1,4) = '2019'
GROUP BY
  person,
  year_month
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

-- This is for all months in 2019 for Benjamin Netanyahu (note that here we capture ALL types of Netanyahu mentions in all urls)

```
WITH
  person_all AS (
  SELECT
    person,
    SUBSTR(CAST(DATE AS STRING), 1,6) AS year_month,
    SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
  FROM
    `gdeltgkgtry.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum`
  WHERE
    domain = 'walla.co.il'
    AND SUBSTR(CAST(DATE AS STRING), 1,4) = '2019'
    AND LOWER(person) LIKE '%in netanyah%'
  GROUP BY
    person,
    year_month )
SELECT
  'Benjamin Netanyahu',
  year_month,
  SUM(all_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  person_all
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  2 ASC;
```